# Problema con funcion y parametros en PHP

Tags: php, funciones

Tengo un problema y es que mi funcion no recibe los parametros de la llamada de la funcion en la pagina que registra los articulos. vease mas abajo:

Me da el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function guardarArticulo(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\DHTML\el_real_final\admin.php on line 59 and exactly 4 expected in C:\xampp\htdocs\DHTML\el_real_final\motor\Funciones.php:190 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\DHTML\el_real_final\admin.php(59): guardarArticulo() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\DHTML\el_real_final\motor\Funciones.php on line 190

Esta es la pagina .php donde llamo a la funcion:
Donde dice guardarArticulos(....);

```
<?php
/*Incluimos el arhivo del header.php*/
include_once("header.php");
?> 

<div class="w3-agile-contact-grids">
            <div class="left-form-w3-agileMIO">
<?php 
    if($_POST)
      {
        //echo"<h2>Formul&aacute;rio enviado</h2>";
        //Recibimos los datos del formulario
        $NombreArt=$_POST['txtNombreArticulo'];
        $Precio=$_POST['txtPrecio'];
       /*No recogemos la foto pues no es obligatoria*/
        $Codigo=$_POST['txtCodigo'];


        //echo" $Nombre $Direccion $Edad $Telefono $Sexo";

         if(empty($NombreArt))
        {
          echo"<h2>Digite nombre del articulo</h2>";
        }
        if(empty($Precio))
        {
          echo"<h2>Debe poner el precio</h2>";
        }

        if(empty($Codigo) )
        {
          echo"<h2>Debe llenar</h2>";
        }


        if(!empty($_FILES['txtFotoArticulo']['name'])){
                    /*Si hay un archivo enviado, guardamos su nombre en         una variable*/
                    $FotoArt=$_FILES['txtFotoArticulo']['name'];

                    /*Reemplazamos los espacios en blanco por _ en el nombre del archivo*/
                    $FotoArt=str_replace(" ","_",$FotoArt);
                    /*Movemos el archivo temporal desde el directorio temporal(tmp) hasta nuestro directorio para los archivos*/
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['txtFotoArticulo']['tmp_name'],'images/upload/'.$FotoArt);
                    chmod('images/upload/'.$FotoArt,0644);
                }       

          if( 
                    (!empty($NombreArt)) && (!empty($Precio)) && (!empty($Codigo)) 
                )
              {
                /*Incluimos el archivo que tiene todas las funciones*/
                include_once("motor/Funciones.php");
                guardarArticulo($NombreArt,$Precio,$Codigo,$FotoArt);

            }

            else 
                          {
                            echo "<h3 id='fallo'>Ha habido un fallo...</h3>
                            <h2 class='validacionphph2'>Faltan campos por completar o llenar </h2>
                                <span id='spanlogin'><a href='Registrate.php' id='log'  class='validacionphph2'>Volver a intentar</a></span>";

                          }



      } else
                  {
                    echo"<h2 class='validacionphph2'>Ning&uacute;n dato enviado</h2>";
                  }





?>

    </div>
    </div>



<?php
/*Incluimos el arhico del footer.php*/
include_once("footer.php");
?>
```

Y esta es la funcion en el .php que recibe los parametros:

```
function guardarArticulo($NombreArt,$Precio,$Codigo,$FotoArt)
{       
//Incluimos el archivo de Conexion
include_once("motor/Conexion.php");
//Nos conectamos al servidor
$Conectarme=Conectar();

//los de inseet el primero es el campo de la tabla de comentario no id lo de parentesis son las tablas como tal en la base de datos
//values son las variables que crees para guardadr los campos de la base de datos ya estan crradas hay que copiar y pegar.
    $Guardar="
        INSERT INTO articulo (NombreDeArticulo, precio, codigo, fotoart )
        VALUES ('$NombreArt', '$Precio', '$Codigo', '$FotoArt') 
    ";


    if(mysqli_query($Conectarme, $Guardar))
    {
      echo "<div>Hemos recibido su foto <a href='admin.php'> Registrar otro</a></div>";

    }
    else
    {
      echo "<div class='Mensaje'>Uff! No hemos podido guardar la foto</div>";

    }       
    /*Cerramos la conexion*/
    mysqli_close($Conectarme);      

}
```

Comment: *Too few arguments to function guardarArticulo(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\DHTML\el_real_final\admin.php on line 59...* Revisa la **línea 59** del archivo **admin.php**. El mensaje dice claramente que desde allí estás llamando la función con **cero argumentos (0 passed)**. El error no es relativo al código que estás mostrando realmente.

Comment: `<?php
     /*Incluimos el arhico del header.php*/
    include_once("motor/Funciones.php");
     //mostrararticulos();
     
     guardarArticulo();
  ?>`

Comment: @camilo ese es el codigo PHP que llama a la fucion en admin.php

Comment: Si llamas a la función así: `guardarArticulo();`, no le estás pasando los 4 parámetros que ella espera: `function guardarArticulo($NombreArt,$Precio,$Codigo,$FotoArt){...` eso es lo que te dice el mensaje de error. ¿Necesitas llamar la función desde `admin.php`? Entonces llámala pasándole los 4 parámetros: `$NombreArt,$Precio,$Codigo,$FotoArt`